# How can I edit propertys of the same control faster?

Tags: c#

Here is a textBox named `textBox1` and I need to edit height/width/text and some more property of it.

Usually we write the code as this:

```
textBox1.text="123";
textBox1.width=555;
textBox1.height=666;
...
```

However, I think it is so inefficient for I should write the `textBox1` again everyline. I wonder if there is a way can be faster? At least not needing write the `textBox1`, again every line.

What's more, faster here means write the code faster but not running faster.

Thank you.

Comment: create a method that uses `TextBox` as a parameter? -- asuming you had the same properties for them.

Comment: You can copy `textBox1.` and paste in every line, so it would be faster, than write it again and again. Or if you change same properties often, you can create method, for example `SetTextBox1(string text, int width, int height, ...)`.

Comment: you can var propss =  `textBox1.GetType().GetProperties();` and itterate over it [properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @MelonNG you might be looking for the `fluent interface`.

Comment: @styx Using reflection to speed up your coding speed is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @vikscool yes,that's what I need.However,it seems only can work on class but not control.Is that right?

Comment: Funnily enough, [VB.Net has a `With` statement that does exactly what you are expecting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/with-end-with-statement). But C# sadly does not (and I don't quite like using it to begin with - but that's just a difference in style I guess).

Comment: Also, if you're really going to argue "faster" in terms of typing speed, you can type the repeated word in one go using [box selection](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2013/07/15/visual-studio-2013-using-box-selection-and-zero-length-box-selection/), effectively removing the repetitive typing effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an extension class for your `TextBox` and return the `textbox` object to get the feel of the `Fluent Interface`.

try the below code:

For the Extension class:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static TextBox setWidth(this TextBox txtBox, Int16 width)
    {
        txtBox.Width = width;
        return txtBox;
    }

    public static TextBox setHeight(this TextBox txtBox, Int16 height)
    {
      //txtBox.Multiline = true; //uncomment this property in order to make the height property work
        txtBox.Height = height;
        return txtBox;
    }

    public static TextBox setText(this TextBox txtBox, string text)
    {
        txtBox.Text = text;
        return txtBox;
    }
}
```

Then use the extension class in the form you want as:

```
textBox1.setWidth(150).setHeight(100).setText("Hi i am an Exteded Text box with fluent");
```

Comment: That's great!Thank you!

Comment: I wonder if there's a Roslyn way of doing this that prevents needing the boilerplate code for every property of every class.

Comment: @MelonNG, do you understand that typing `textBox1` 3 times is a minor annoyance, and adding 3 extensions method to your project is a lot of work - consider the time you need to spend to write, test, document and maintain those 3 methods - and probably you will prefer to CtrlC,CtrlV `textBox1`, or use VS Intellisense completion, or declare a short variable like`var t = textBox1; t.Width = 555, t.Height = 666; t.Text = "wow, it is fast";`

Comment: @ASh I meet a strange situation that sometimes need to change the name of control.However if I use ctrl+h to replace it all,it will replace something other text not belong to control,or I should replce it one by one.I don't want to do that so I want to find a better solution that only replace one to do it.

Comment: @MelonNG, rename control via PropertyWindow in VS. Vs with replace all usages properly

Answer (score 0):

If it is only about being able to write code faster then not the best idea, but what you could probably do is write tb1 instead of textBox1, and once you're done search specific file for 'tb1' and replace all instances with 'textBox1'.

To find and replace in VS, default shortcut is Ctrl + H. Type in 'tb1' in Find field and 'textBox1' in replcae field. Then, you could either go 'Replace next' or 'Replace all' ...former will highlight the word before replacement for verification, and later will replace all matching instances.

Comment: What you said it is just I am worried about.Whenever I need to change the name of a control.I can only to replace it by Ctrl+H.